# run keyword if error invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)

Tags: robotframework

I am new to this run keyword if method.

I wanted to enter different number based on specific page.

e.g. if page1 element is detected then input number 1, if page2 then input number 2.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library
Library    Collections
Resource   ../Resources/nine-res-work.robot

*** Variables ***
${LOGIN-BUTTON-NUMBER-1}   ${ANDROID-WIDGET-TEXT-VIEW}\[@resource-id="com.test.abc.work.cac:id/btn_number" and @text="1"]
${LOGIN-BUTTON-NUMBER-2}   ${ANDROID-WIDGET-TEXT-VIEW}\[@resource-id="com.test.abc.work.cac:id/btn_number" and @text="2"]
${LOGIN-BUTTON-NUMBER-3}   ${ANDROID-WIDGET-TEXT-VIEW}\[@resource-id="com.test.abc.work.cac:id/btn_number" and @text="3"]

${LOGIN-PAGE-HEARDER-page1}         ${ANDROID-WIDGET-TEXT-VIEW}\[@resource-id="com.test.abc.work.cac:id/headerText" and @text="Enter your PIN."]
${LOGIN-PAGE-HEARDER-page2}               ${ANDROID-WIDGET-TEXT-VIEW}\[@resource-id="com.test.abc.work.cac:id/headerText" and @text="Enter your passcode."]


*** Keywords ***
Smart Card Login
    Run Keyword If  ${LOGIN-PAGE-HEARDER-page1} == 'PASS'   Tap     ${LOGIN-BUTTON-NUMBER-1}
    Run Keyword If  ${LOGIN-PAGE-HEARDER-page2} == 'PASS'   Tap     ${LOGIN-BUTTON-NUMBER-2}

*** Test Cases ***
Test 1
    Launch Application
    Smart Card Login
```

error

```
Test 1  | FAIL |
Evaluating expression '//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id="com.test.abc.work.cac:id/headerText" and @text="Enter your PIN."] == 'PASS'' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

**I have tried another way, this time no error but the tap action isn't execute.**

```
*** Variables ***
${LOGIN-BUTTON-NUMBER-1}   ${ANDROID-WIDGET-TEXT-VIEW}\[@resource-id="com.test.abc.work.cac:id/btn_number" and @text="1"]
${LOGIN-BUTTON-NUMBER-2}   ${ANDROID-WIDGET-TEXT-VIEW}\[@resource-id="com.test.abc.work.cac:id/btn_number" and @text="2"]
${LOGIN-BUTTON-NUMBER-3}   ${ANDROID-WIDGET-TEXT-VIEW}\[@resource-id="com.test.abc.work.cac:id/btn_number" and @text="3"]

${LOGIN-PAGE-HEARDER-page1}         ${ANDROID-WIDGET-TEXT-VIEW}\[@text="Enter your PIN."]
${LOGIN-PAGE-HEARDER-page2}               ${ANDROID-WIDGET-TEXT-VIEW}\[@text="Enter your passcode."]


*** Keywords ***
Input App Passcode
    Tap     ${LOGIN-BUTTON-NUMBER-2}


*** Test Cases ***
Launch App
    Open Nine Folders Application
    Sleep   5s

Input Password
    ${Page1} =    Page Should Contain Element    ${LOGIN-PAGE-HEARDER-page1}
    Run Keyword If      '${Page1}' == 'PASS'      Input App Passcode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got syntax error because `Run Keyword If` expects a valid Python condition as first argument. This is not the case in your code. In your case this is what happens, assuming `${ANDROID-WIDGET-TEXT-VIEW}` is just `view` in this example:

```
Run Keyword If  ${LOGIN-PAGE-HEARDER-page1} == 'PASS'   Tap     ${LOGIN-BUTTON-NUMBER-1}
```

which is

```
Run Keyword If  view\[@resource-id="com.test.abc.work.cac:id/headerText" and @text="Enter your PIN."] == 'PASS'   Tap     ${LOGIN-BUTTON-NUMBER-1}
```

this is equivalent with the following Python code:

```
if view\[@resource-id="com.test.abc.work.cac:id/headerText" and @text="Enter your PIN."] == 'PASS':
    call_tap_function(LOGIN_BUTTON_NUMBER_1)
```

There are a bunch of invalid characters there because the string is not enclosed in `'`. So correctly it should be:

```
Run Keyword If  '${LOGIN-PAGE-HEARDER-page1}' == 'PASS'   Tap     ${LOGIN-BUTTON-NUMBER-1}
```

which will translate to:

```
if 'view\[@resource-id="com.test.abc.work.cac:id/headerText" and @text="Enter your PIN."]' == 'PASS':
    call_tap_function(LOGIN_BUTTON_NUMBER_1)
```

**Note that** this will never be equal with `PASS`.

---

As for your second approach, `Page Should Contain Element` does not have a return value, it will fail or the execution continues as usual. To achieve what you want you should use the [Run Keyword And Return Status](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status) that will return if the keyword called has passed or failed.

```
Input Password
    ${Page1} =    Run Keyword And Return Status    Page Should Contain Element    ${LOGIN-PAGE-HEARDER-page1}
    Run Keyword If      ${Page1}      Input App Passcode
```

Here `${Page1}` variable will be `true` if `Page Should Contain Element` passed, aka if login page header page1 was on the page.